# How to programmatically (with Javascript) set a narrow window size with the new Chrome version (from v69)?

Tags: angular, google-chrome, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

We have some UATs (user acceptance tests) which run in Jenkins with the Chromedriver, and some of them do not run anymore since the protractor (Javascript Angular UI-Test framework) **cannot set browser-width size under 552px**.

Also manually you cannot resize the window-width to like 320px (iphone 5 wide) anymore with the newer Chrome version. (except developer tools and mobile simulation)

Is there any way achieving this? Setting the windows size manually to any size like 320px * 500px?

PS: In protractor.conf you can define a global resolution, but this is not what we want since we also have tests, where we also need to change the resolution in the middle of a test.

Old way, which does not work for narrow sizes anymore:

```
browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(320, 568).then(() => {
  browser.manage().window().getSize().then(function (windowSize) {
    console.log('Used Resolution  ' + windowSize.width + ' x ' + windowSize.height);
  });
  callback();
}, callback);
```

output: Used Resolution 552 * 568